# What is the meaning of "its" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Writing Finnegans Wake (1928-38), his final work, in a largely
>   idiosyncratic language, a book in which the words are skewed from
>   normal meaning, Joyce transcribed his symptoms, according to Lacan; he
>   converted his sickness into art, his compulsions into his way of life,
>   his symptoms into his personal style as a human and as an artist. The
>   meeting of Joyce with his symptom is an encounter with the Real made
>   possible by
>   **its** conversion into an artistic process.

This section is from an article named "Real and Immanence in Cinema" by Daniela Angelucci.

Here's the link: http://www.consecutio.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/8-angelucci-online.pdf

There is no comma in the sentence. I couldn't figure out if it means 'his symptom' or 'the Real.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the antecedent of "it's" is not just "his symptom" or "the Real", but rather "the meeting" of the two.
The meeting [of the symptom with the Real] is converted into an artistic process.